# Can't update nvidia driver, hanging indefinitely during installation

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, cinnamon

Running cinnamon, linux mint 19 Tara

I'm trying to upgrade from 470.57.01, to 525.116.04

I downloaded the .run file from nvidia

I opened up a new terminal with control alt f2

I stopped lightdm with sudo service lightdm stop

I tried running it with sudo sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-525.116.04.run

It goes to the screen with a green bar at the top of the page "NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64"
And a white bar at the bottom "NVIDIA software installer for unix/linux

and thats it, it just hangs forever.

any ideas?

Comment: Is there enough free space?

Comment: theres just 2.4gb free in my file system of 30gb originally, but 40gb in my drive overall
no idea why its partitioned like that, seems like its cutting it close, I don't remember doing that

Comment: Installing nvidia drivers this way has a number of drawbacks. Have you considered [this PPA from Canonical](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)?

Comment: I had not, but I have some very sensitive security requirements on this computer and so I can't afford to add any additional attack surface